# I am trying to convert UTF-8 file to UTF-8-BOM using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, utf-8

This is the below code i am using.

```
$file="final.txt"
$MyRawString = Get-Content -Raw "$file"
$Utf8BomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8BOMEncoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $MyRawString, $Utf8BomEncoding)
```

Comment: Note: you are asking an "illegal things" for Unicode. Unicode allows BOM in UTF-8 if it is needed for round-trip conversion, but it should never be added. And you are doing the conversion to Unicode more difficult (in future when Microsoft finally will convert to UTF-8 you will have to remove the BOM). Users in other OS will see garbage (and also most text tools will not work properly).

Comment: Hi Nid, and welcome to stack overflow. In your question, you've posted the code but you haven't said in what way it's going wrong. Is it erroring? Or is it running but not producing the right output?
Remember, it's encouraged here to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70151266/edit) your question as much as you like, to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to output utf8 **with** BOM, you should create `$Utf8BomEncoding` with parameter `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier` set to `$true`.

Next, using method `WriteAllLines()` is actually meant for writing out an array of lines, so you should either remove the `-Raw` switch from `Get-Content`, or use the `WriteAllText()` method.

Try

PowerShell versions up to and including 5.1:

```
Get-Content -Path 'final.txt' -Encoding UTF8 | Set-Content -Path 'final_BOM.txt' -Encoding UTF8
```

PowerShell versions above 5.1:

```
Get-Content -Path 'final.txt' -Encoding UTF8 | Set-Content -Path 'final_BOM.txt' -Encoding utf8BOM
```

or use .Net methods. Note you need to use **absolute, full paths**

```
$Utf8NoBOM   = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
$Utf8WithBOM = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($true)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('X:\final_BOM.txt', [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('X:\final.txt', $Utf8NoBOM), $Utf8WithBOM)
```